# Deduplication in nutch 1.11 for sites having same content and different URI

Tags: nutch

I am using nutch to crawl over intranet sites. I came across a scenario in which 2 sites have same content (compared the view source of both sites using notepad++) but different URI.
e.g.

```
http://site_name.domain_name.com/a/b/c/index.html
http://site_name.domain_name.com/x/y/z/index.html
```

Nutch is indexing either of them but not the both.

How to alter this behavior of nutch and index both of the URLs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Nutch use the `org.apache.nutch.crawl.MD5Signature` class to calculate the digest of an URL, this class calculates the digest using the `MD5Hash` function of the raw binary content of the page, if no content is found then the URL is used.

The `DeduplicationJob` first groups fetched URLs by the digest (in your case both URLs should have the same signature/digest) and marks all the URLs as duplicated, except the one with the highest score, if both (or more) URLs have the same digest and the same score, then the one with the latest timestamp is used instead.

In your particular case I think that a custom implementation of `org.apache.nutch.crawl.Signature` that takes into account **both** parameters (the URL and the text/raw content) should solve your problem. This is required because the existing signature implementations `MD5Signature`, `TextMD5Signature` and `TextProfileSignature` will only consider the URL if no text/raw content is found for a given URL. Nevertheless the implementation should be pretty straightforward.

Keep in mind that this could generate more duplicated URLs in your index.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your explanation.Will keep the default MD5Signature one as In the end I am only concerned about content.